# Reading values from json mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL JSON objects and the object saved in the database is as follow

`{"additionalSlots": [{"date": null, "count": 0}, {"date": 1564127223311, "count": 1000}]}`

What I'm trying to do is to read all the dates and update the count to 0 of the specific object if the date is greater than the current date.

Are there any ways to achieve this?

UPDATE :

I was able to loop though using this

```
DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_mysql_while_loop$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE test_mysql_while_loop()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE x  INT;
DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE json  VARCHAR(4000);
  DECLARE w  INT;

 SET x = 0;
 SET str =  '';
 SELECT 
   JSON_LENGTH(additionalslots ,"$.additionalSlots") INTO w
FROM 
   user_detail;

 WHILE x  < w DO

    SELECT 
        JSON_EXTRACT(additionalslots ,CONCAT('$.additionalSlots[',x,']')) INTO json
    FROM 
        user_detail;

 SET  x = x + 1; 
 END WHILE;

 SELECT json;
 END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL test_mysql_while_loop();
```

Now what I need to do is to remove the value if the date is passed or date is null. How can I achieve that?

The result I'm expecting is

From this

`{"additionalSlots": [{"date": null, "count": 0}, {"date": 1564127223311, "count": 1000}]}`

To this

`{"additionalSlots": [{"date": 1564127223311, "count": 1000}]}`

Comment: Check [12.17 JSON Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html).

Comment: @wchiquito Hi I did try.                                                                               
SELECT userid,JSON_EXTRACT(additionalslots ,"$.date") FROM user_detail;   this always returns null.                                                                                          
I'm kinda struck on this any help would be great :D

Comment: @wchiquito I also tried this query SELECT userid,JSON_EXTRACT(additionalslots ,"$.additionalSlots") FROM user_detail; and this returned me [{"date": null, "count": 0}, {"date": 1564127223311, "count": 1000}] . What i want is the date object . How can i access that

Comment: @wchiquito I tried this query as well which returned the date object . SELECT userid,JSON_EXTRACT(additionalslots ,"$.additionalSlots[1].date") FROM user_detail; The problem is i want to add a event that runs every 5 minutes to check the date and update the count

Comment: can you please specify MySQL version?

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde .  Ver 8.0.16 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew) .

Comment: I recommend that you update your question with all the comments mentioned, also, add tabla's structure, some sample data and the result you expect.

Comment: @wchiquito okay will do

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do acheive it using

```
DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS removeadditionalhits$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE removeadditionalhits()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE x  INT;
  DECLARE w  INT;

 SET x = 0;
 SET str =  '';
 SELECT 
   JSON_LENGTH(additionalhits ,"$.additionalSlots") INTO w
FROM 
   user_detail;

 WHILE x  < w DO

    SELECT
        JSON_EXTRACT(additionalhits ,CONCAT('$.additionalSlots[',x,']'))
    FROM
        user_detail
    WHERE
         now() >  FROM_UNIXTIME(JSON_EXTRACT(additionalhits ,CONCAT('$.additionalSlots[',x,'].date'))/1000) ; 


    UPDATE 
        user_detail
    SET
        additionalhits = JSON_REMOVE(additionalhits ,CONCAT('$.additionalSlots[',x,']'))
    WHERE
        now() >  FROM_UNIXTIME(JSON_EXTRACT(additionalhits ,CONCAT('$.additionalSlots[',x,'].date'))/1000) ; 

 SET  x = x + 1; 
 END WHILE; END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL removeadditionalslots();
```

Comment: A version that can be useful with some changes, [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95a0503dddd87a0b5e2ce7d7f534ece7).